# I try to run a script through TextWrangler - no module as matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have Python 3.6 installed on my Mac OS X. When I wrote my script I wrote the following

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

but then when I run it, I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Users/YoavPoni/Documents/Python/TextWranglerRunTemp-sen.py‌​", line
>   4, in  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Any suggestions?

Comment: run the command : pip install matplotlib

Comment: I did, and when I run it it tells me that the requirement is already satisfied

Comment: Can you post the full error message you are getting?

Comment: not sure if it shows my picture

Comment: ================================================================================
Jun 5, 2017, 10:59:54 AM
~/Documents/Python/sen.py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/YoavPoni/Documents/Python/TextWranglerRunTemp-sen.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Answer (score 1):

You might need to change the Python you are invoking when running the program. Currently, you may be using the standard Python that comes from Mac OS X (that does not have matplotlib installed). What you need to do is run your code with the Python that has matplotlib installed in its library.

You should include a line at the beginning of your Python code like

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

With `/usr/bin/env` being the full path to the Python interpreter with matplotlib installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older post, but for the future...

The method used to install Python 3.6 affects both how (and where) it was installed. Further, the method used may not properly update and honor the Mac's environment. The error references TextWrangler (BBEdit) and I've found the easiest way to avoid such problems in the editor is to reference the intended version of Python in the script shebang line explicitly as @cosinepenguin suggests. Moreover, it's good practice to ensure that the script is only run under compatible versions of Python.

So to extend the answer, consider these examples (I'm using Python 2.7, because I don't have 3.6 installed). They're just examples of how the shebang line makes a difference--the proper one may or may not match one of the examples.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pytz
```

loads with out error.  However, this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pytz
```

doesn't.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled text 40", line 4, in <module>
    import pytz
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

But this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pytz
```

is also problem free.

The exact right construction depends on where the aftermarket Python version is installed. There are ways to edit the Mac's environment variable to include the location of the aftermarket Python 3.6 installation, but that can be tricky and can really mess things up if you don't do it properly. So my advice is to reference your target Python version with the shebang line and leave the environment variable alone if possible.

Now on to Matplotlib. AFAIK, Mac OSes have shipped with Matplotlib installed from the factory (for its installed Python versions), but it could be that the Python 3.6 install doesn't have it. To install the library, I would strongly suggest using `pip` (I believe that Python 3.6 comes with `pip` already installed.) There are lots of tutorials online (and on SO) on how to use `pip`.